# Huawei Ascend P7: "Log In WiFi Network", but WiFi works well, and a very strange issue

Tags: wi-fi, huawei, huawei-ascend-p7

I have a problem with my Huawei Ascend P7

The cell phone connects perfectly to WiFi but I have several problems related to this:

1. Repeatedly asks me to "Log in WiFi network".
2. Certainly, it connects to the internet, but only for a few moments, the speed 
   of the connection goes down until it is constantly lost (for long periods of 
   time).

> EDIT: Well, I tried connecting in my cousin's WiFi and worked, now I
>   know that the issue happens only in my WiFi

**Important data:**

1. This problem does not happen when I connect to a HotSpot, or a public network 
   (which asks me to login)
2. My router works perfectly.
3. Update the ROM (officially) to Lollipop 5.1.1

**"Strange" things that happen in this case**

1. The notification of "start session in wifi network" appears for a few seconds, and then disappears.

> Once I was able to open the notification, I could even "log in" to my Wi-Fi 
>        network with Google Sites, but nothing happened

2. The problem suddenly appeared, I do not know when it happened.

**I tried:**

1. Change to static IP.
2. Check the "Wireless" section of my router
3. Reset my phone.
4. Wipe data

I hope to find help to solve this problem, this is the only phone that I will have for a long time (that's why I updated it)

Of course, thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Check to see if wifi service is actually an app called tispy ..
It hides under the name wifi service